# Retrieve core-data model version from appDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, core-data-migration

Anybody knows how to get the core-data model version when the app starts?

I've implemented the lightweight migration and it works fine but I need to check if the sqlite db is based to the old model version before the migration process starts.

In the new model I added a new entity but I need to populate it with value of an entity of the old model. I want to do that only one time.

Is there a way to do it in the appdelegate?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: AFAIK Core Data will only attempt to perform the lightweight migration if it sees that it needs to. If it has already done it, it won't try again. You should be able to put your entity-specific code in the migration method.

Comment: Yep, but I suppose core data compares the model version at startup so it knows if perform the migration or not. I though there was this info somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting the DB-version in my preferences (.plist). So if I change the DB, I set the new DB-version in there and store the version from the last start in the `NSUserDefaults`.

```
NSNumber *newDbVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"DBVersion"];
NSNumber *oldDbVersion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DBVersion"];

if (oldDbVersion == nil)
{
    // part without handling, so you know the max db version.
}else
{
    if([oldDbVersion intValue] < [newDbVersion intValue])
    {
        // try the liteweight migration and if that failed, migrate by hand
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will use the same approach. Max